# AJAX not returning expected output from PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have index.php page where i want to have two "Select" elements. However I want second "Select" element to show up after one option was selected from the first one, and the second "Select" element will always contain different options based on what was selected in the first element. Both elements are reading data from MySql database. Therefore I've created another page called script.php which will hold second element until first one was selected and using jquery .load() it will load it right next to first element. But i need to transfer value from the first element to that script.php using AJAX request so it can return second elements with specific options. When I test each part separately it works fine (ajax request is passing data to script.php, script.php is loading when #first element is selected, when i open script.php page on it's own, it's giving #second just the way it should be). But when i put all this together as it is describe bellow, I am getting #second element without any options inside of it.

Here is index.php

```
//this is first select element and it works fine

echo '<select id="first">';
$data = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES FROM something");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
echo '<option>' . $row[0] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

// this is placeholder for second select element
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Here is script.php:

```
// this variable will hold selected option from ajax request
$selected = $_POST['selectedOption'];
// this is second element and it works fine when it's not called from another page
echo '<select id="second">';
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * TABLES FROM $selected");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
echo '<option>' . $row['column'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Here is ajax.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("change", '#first', function(event) {

// grabbing value of first element 
var selectedOption = $('#first option:selected').val();


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'script.php',
    data: "selectedOption=" + selectedOption,
    cache: false

});

//calling #second element to show up (script.php) in this case

$('#placeholder').load("script.php");

});
});
```

Hopefully i managed to explain my problem so you can understand it. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) you're open to SQL injection. 2) where is your success/error callback? This is where you get the data from ajax 3) place `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your ajax script to see if there are any errors

Comment: As for SQL injection - you have a point, but this code was simplified so people can understand easier what bothers me. When i tried to simplify the code i've left out callback by mistake, but anyway it wasn't doing anything until @JonJ pointed out to me what should be there. And I wasn't aware of those display_errors functions, i'll try to learn more about them. Your answer is really appreciated, i still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'script.php',
    data: "selectedOption=" + selectedOption,
    cache: false
    success: function(result) {
        $("#placeholder").html(result);
    }
});
```

The Ajax call is asynchronous, you want to set the second select element after the data was returned.

Comment: Sehr gut!
Thanks mate! It works like a charm now!
You've managed to resolve it in matter of minutes, while i was struggling with it for last 2+ hours. 
Really appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help, but be aware regarding @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs comment regarding SQL injection. You should parameterize your MySQL calls. https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Will do! Cheers!